# When I use a .fullScreenCover and a DatePicker on the screen, dismissing the full screen with the calendar open will not leave the fullscreen

Tags: swiftui

As long as the datePicker selection is closed, everything is fine.  When the calendar sheet is left open, and the dismiss (.onTapGesture) is pressed, the onDismiss closure is done, but the screen will not return.  Tried setting the isPresenting to false in the didDismiss() with the same results.

getting this error

[Presentation] Attempt to present <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x116808680> on <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_: 0x116a09230> (from <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_: 0x116a09230>) which is already presenting <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x1168043a0>.

Took this code from the documentation and added a DatePicker to make things a simple a possible.

```
     struct FullScreenCoverPresentedOnDismiss: View {
     @State private var isPresenting = false
     @State private var birthDate = Date()
     var body: some View {
         Button("Present Full-Screen Cover") {
             isPresenting.toggle()
         }
         .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresenting,
                          onDismiss: didDismiss) {
             VStack {
                 DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                     Text("Select a date")
                 }
                 Text("A full-screen modal view.")
                     .font(.title)
                 Text("Tap to Dismiss")
                     .onTapGesture {
                                          isPresenting.toggle()
                                      }
             }

             .foregroundColor(.white)
             .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                    maxHeight: .infinity)
             .background(Color.blue)
             .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
         }
     }

     func didDismiss() {
         print("didDismiss")
     }
 }
```

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue. All works well for me, on macos 12.1-beta, using xcode 13.2-beta. With or without the calendar showing, when I "Tap to Dismiss", the 
sheet is closed and the "Present Full-Screen Cover" is shown. 
Tested on real devices, ios-15 and macos 12.1-beta (Catalyst). It may be different on older systems.

Comment: Thanks...I'm on macOS 12.0.1 and Xcode 13.1  I will give it another try when the betas become real.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing on iOS 15.4. Launched my app yesterday and this bug came up during onboarding. Wrapping dismiss() in DispatchQueue.main.async to allow DatePicker to dismiss first

Comment: just retested and getting the same results...are you saying the wrapping the dismiss() fixes it, and do you have an example of what code you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I found was to wrap the thing you want to present after the date picker is dismissed like this

```
// Adjust the delay as needed (I've used 0.25 secs with success) 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { 
    showingConfirmationDialog = true
}
```